# Convert SVG group into a 3D shape | adding thickness with Three.js

Tags: svg, three.js

Is there a way to convert an SVG group of paths into its 3D counterpart?
In a way, It's like adding thickness to it.

I used **SVGLoader** to import my svg path into **THREE.JS** library:

```
loader.load(
    './test.svg',
    function ( data ) {

        const paths = data.paths;
    

        for ( let i = 0; i < paths.length; i ++ ) {

            const path = paths[ i ];

            const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {
                color: 0x337ab7,
                side: THREE.DoubleSide,
                depthWrite: false,
                opacity: 1,
                transparent: true
            } );

            const shapes = path.toShapes( true );

            for ( let j = 0; j < shapes.length; j ++ ) {

                const shape = shapes[ j ];
                const geometry = new THREE.ShapeBufferGeometry( shape );
                const mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
                group.add( mesh );

            }

        }...
```

The **SVG** upload works fine.
Do you know any library or trickery to accomplish this **3D transformation**?

[image]

Comment: Instead of creating `ShapeBufferGeometry`, have you already tried it with [ExtrudeBufferGeometry](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/geometries/ExtrudeBufferGeometry)?

Comment: haha ok It works with that. @Mugen87 make an answer and I'll vote you. That solved my problem!

Comment: Okay, adding an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating ShapeBufferGeometry try it with [ExtrudeBufferGeometry](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/geometries/ExtrudeBufferGeometry). It should be exactly what you are looking for.